# Are there preferred alternate ports for Tomcat installations?

Tags: tomcat

The default port for Tomcat (and other "secondary" web servers/servlet containers) is 8080.

If there are multiple services configured for this port or there is a need to install multiple instances of Tomcat on a server then you can can edit this port value in ${CATALINA_HOME}/conf/server.xml.

Is there a standard for determining what port number(s) that other installations should use? Is there a standard +1/+10/+100/+1000 approach that is typically followed? Is there a way to determine if there is conflicts without picking something and just trying it?

Also, in server.xml, there is by default:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN"> 
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443" /> 
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```

For additional Tomcat installations, do all of these need to be renumbered/included? Should they each follow the same renumbering strategy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to determine if there is conflicts without picking
>   something and just trying it?

The latest version of Tomcat 7.0.25 includes functionality to automatically find and bind to a free port. This isn't great for any kind of production installation but is pretty neat for testing and development purposes.

To answer your original question, I quite like 9090 when 8080 is taken but I'm not aware of any specific best practice in this area.

The Tomcat docs which describe auto port binding are [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/cluster-receiver.html).

And yes, all the other ports will need to be changed as well.

Comment: I think the ultimate answer is that there is no prescribed pattern to use, but whatever you do, be consistent. I went with the +1000 approach for my specific situation. I accepted this answer because it confirms that all ports should be changed.

Answer (score 2):

If you bind multiple tomcats on the same IP address, you will need to use different ports on the connectors, and set them manually in the server.xml file.

I always used +1 by personnal convention.

Answer (score 2):

I quite like the +10000 approach. Although there are well known services that go beyond port 10000 per default, many well known applications do not. Therefore the additional ports are quite recognizable.

For instance:

- Tomcats: 8080, 18080, 28080
- Secure Tomcats: 8443, 18443, 28443
- iSCSI targets: 3260, 13260, 23260

... and so on.